# Access to fetch at '' from origin '' has been blocked by CORS policy: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource

Tags: aws-lambda, cors, aws-api-gateway

I have this api (method get) that is connected to a lambda function that does a simple select from a database, if i test the endpoint with postman with a null body it does work (if i understood, postman is not under the same CORS policy), as well as typing the endpoint on the browser.
[image: postman]

[image: browser]

But when i try to do a fetch from a simple js, i get the error :
Access to fetch at '...' from origin 'http://localhost' has been blocked by CORS policy: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource. If an opaque response serves your needs, set the request's mode to 'no-cors' to fetch the resource with CORS disabled.

[image]

I enabled CORS in API Gateway, both with the Enable CORS option
[image]
and with the Enable API Gateway CORS when creating a new resource [image]

If i test my endpoint with gateway, i also get that Allow-content-allow-origin : * is in my response header :
[image]

What should i do to fix this problem?

here is the JS fetch :

```
    console.log("pre fetch");

Show();
console.log("post fetch");
function Show(){
fetch("...").then(onResponse);//.then(onJson);
}
function onResponse(response){
    console.log(response);
    return response.json();
}
```

I removed the onJson to avoid confusion, but even with that in its the same problem.

Comment: You shouldn't be sending a body with a GET request. While not strictly prohibited by the spec it is unconventional and some servers may reject it.

Comment: what do you mean? i am not, at least im not aware of it.

Comment: My bad. Misread the screenshot. What are your request headers set to?

Comment: i didnt set them, never did that with a get request. If you instead mean in the API gateway, i setted nothing but those enabled automatically by enabling CORS or putting Lambda integration

Comment: This did the trick for me: https://stackoverflow.com/a/58405153/3987765.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Try to include that in your function too, like this,
I hope this would work:

```
const headers = {'Content-Type':'application/json',
                    'Access-Control-Allow-Origin':'*',
                    'Access-Control-Allow-Methods':'POST,PATCH,OPTIONS'}
const response = {
    statusCode: 200,
    headers:headers,
    body: JSON.stringify(X),
};
return response;
```

Here **X** is the response that you want to return.

Comment: Dont know, i cant still up/dowvote because of low reputation. Thanks for the reply, btw. 
I solved by putting a simple string in the enable cors headers, so i dont think this was the solution to my problem - but thanks anyway. If i can do something for the downvote let me know.

Comment: No worries, if it is solved then good.  :D

Comment: Don't be sorry, no worries, coding should be fun and I think some people really hate CORS  XD

Comment: @KnowledgeGainer  Your solution solved my issue. You are a rockstar! Thank you so much!

Comment: @DmitriSanzharov Glad to help you.

Answer (score 4):

If you are using Node.js you needs to install cors.
npm install cors.
After installing cors, include it in the page where you are using fetch function as shown below;
const cors = require('cors');
app.use(cors());
and the error will be solved.

Comment: I'm (i was) using Node.js as the runtime language for the lambda function,  i solved the problem just by adding 'Origin' into the allow Control Allow Headers field of enable cors, so i dont think this was really the response to this problem, at least for me. Thanks anyway!

Answer (score 1):

I made [a video](https://youtu.be/nJXkFgG5TbQ) on how to fix this.

You need to go into the Lambda function and add special code:

original (does NOT work):

```
exports.handler = async (event) => {
    // TODO implement
    const response = {
        statusCode: 200,
        body: JSON.stringify('Hello from Lambda!'),
    };
    return response;
};
```

new one, that works:

```
exports.handler = async (event) => {
    // TODO implement
    const response = {
        statusCode: 200,
                headers: {
            "Access-Control-Allow-Headers" : "Content-Type",
            "Access-Control-Allow-Origin": "*",
            "Access-Control-Allow-Methods": "OPTIONS,POST,GET"
        },
        body: JSON.stringify('Hello from Lambda!'),
    };
    return response;
};
```

You can find this solution in here: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/apigateway/latest/developerguide/how-to-cors.html

Only you need to replace the:

```
  "Access-Control-Allow-Origin": "https://www.example.com",
```

with

```
            "Access-Control-Allow-Origin": "*",
```

Special thanks to user, KnowledgeGainer

ALSO, you need to enable CORS on Gateway API side, just follow instruction from here: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/apigateway/latest/developerguide/how-to-cors-console.html

Comment: thanks for the reply! i solved the problem just by adding 'Origin' into the allow Control Allow Headers field of enable cors, so i dont think this is really the response to this problem, or maybe this also works? Also thanks forthe references, its always good to have something more to try :)

Comment: Yeah, I tried that originally to, but didn't work for me, for some reason. But the Headers into lambda worked. Anyway, we are unstoppable now. Next challenge here we come! Boom!  =)

Answer (score 0):

For Lambda function URL:

In the AWS console, go to *Lambda* -> *Functions* -> (select the function) -> *Configuration* -> *Function URL* -> *Edit*.

Check *Configure cross-origin resource sharing (CORS)* and enter `*` for *Allow origin*, *Allow headers*, and *Allow methods*

*Save*.